# What is the problem in return of function 'str'? Can anyone explain how to return string after passing string in a function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char* str(char ( *p)[50])
{
    strrev(*p);
    return p[50];
}

int main()
{
    char a[50]; 
    fgets(a,50,stdin);
    str(&a);
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I wrote to understand the passing and return of string to a function.

I am getting the output but not able to understand what is happening.

Could anyone explain the code on how to pass the string in function and return string from a function
through pointers.

Comment: You don't need to take the address of an array when passing it to a function. When you pass an array, it's converted to a pointer automatically.

Comment: `return p[50];` is invalid. `p` is a pointer to an array, not an array. And the indexes of the array it points to go from 0 to 49.

Comment: [so] is not a programming school. You should read a textbook or tutorial that explain how pointers are passed to functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example is diabolical, and nobody writes C this way.  Please, just do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* str(char *p)
{
    return strrev(p);
}

int main()
{
    char a[50]; 
    fgets(a, 50, stdin);
    printf("%s", str(a));
    return 0;
}
```

As already mentioned in the comments, an array automatically decays to a pointer.  There's no need to try and take the address of the array itself.  Also mentioned is that your `return p[50];` statement was completely invalid.

The usual paradigm here is to return the string (which was modified in-place) so that it can be used directly, which I have done in my example by calling the function and using the return value on the same line when calling `printf`.  In fact, even `strrev` follows this convention, so again I've leveraged that in the example for your `str` function.